# how can I embed a civicontribute page in wordpress with gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

I cant see how to embedd a civicontribute page using gutenberg, any thoughts?

Comment: Wordpress 5.1.1
CiviCRM 5.11.0

Comment: The civiguide appears to be out of date for Wordpress 5.1.1: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/online-contributions/#page-or-post-in-wordpress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok eventually worked this out, with help from the civi sysadmin guide [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/#shortcodes-in-gutenberg-editor-available-as-a-plugin-for-versions-49x-and-prior). You can create a shortcode block, and just add your CiviContribute shortcodes in there, [civicrm component="contribution" id="x"], and it will  embed that form in the page. I will see about updating the civicrm documentation to make this more obvious for people like me :)

Comment: thank you for taking the positive step of contributing to the documentation